# Embed image at cursor while composing Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to insert an embedded image where the cursor is localized.

Every macro I found opens a new mail window and I want it to run on an email while the user is composing the mail.

```
Sub blaa()
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    objMail.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\ieinati\Pictures\AAA.png"
    objMail.HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:AAA.png' height=460 width=60>"
    objMail.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're creating a new MailItem rather than getting a reference to the currently open. Below shows how to access the CurrentItem in the ActiveInspector.

**Edit: you need to add the existing HTMLBody first before adding the new image.**

This code assumes the rest of your code is correct:

```
Sub blaa()

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

objMail.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\ieinati\Pictures\AAA.png"
objMail.HTMLBody = objMail.HTMLBody & "<img src='cid:AAA.png' height=460 width=60>"
objMail.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: that's greet for the first part! Thank you!

however, right now when i activate the macro, it delete all the text that was in the message. how can i make the image embed where the cursor is currently localized??

Comment: @whylikethis I've included an edit and updated the code too

Comment: You cannot concatenate 2 HTML strings and expect the resulting string to be a valid HTML string. The two must be merged.